# Asymptotic behavior of $ \int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{x^2 \exp(-(x-a)^2)}{1+Aa^{-1}\exp(-x^2/(1+a^2))} dx$ as $a\to 0$

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, indefinite-integrals, riemann-integration, gaussian-integral

Let $a>0$ and $A>0$, I am looking for the decay rate of the integral
$$ \int^\infty_{-\infty}  \frac{x^2 \exp(-(x-a)^2)}{1+Aa^{-1}\exp(-x^2/(1+a^2))} dx \quad \text{ as $a\to 0$}.$$
There is no closed form answer for the integral. I have tried on Matlab that it should converge to zero much faster than power growth. I think the growth should be exponential types. Do we have some literature discussing this kind of issue? Thanks!

I have successfully obtained the growth rate of
$$ \int^\infty_{M} +\int_{-\infty}^{-M}  \frac{x^2 \exp(-(x-a)^2)}{1+Aa^{-1}\exp(-x^2/(1+a^2))} dx \quad \text{ as $a\to 0$}$$
be expanding the denominator in power series.

But I do not know to deal with the integral in $[-M,M]$.

Comment: Can you analyze the denominator for $a\rightarrow 0$? Should help.

Comment: What does it mean? It is hard to do that since it is inside the integral.

Comment: And yet you can decide which term is larger for every $x$, right?

Comment: yes!.....................

Comment: try breaking the integral into 2 ranges (or possibly 3 ranges) based on what dominates the denominator.

Comment: then to apply the power series of $1/(1+x)$?

Answer (score 2):

Let us assume $a\ll1$.  Approximating the function (or simply plotting it), we can see that the maximum of the integrand is at $|x|\geq 1$ (in fact it is $|x|=1$ for $A\ll a$ and becomes larger when increasing $A$).

Because if this we can approximate $1+a^2 \approx 1$ and $(x-a)^2 \approx x^2$ in the exponents of the integrand to obtain the leading order behavior.

Denoting the integral by $I(a,A)$, we obtain
$$ I(a,A) \simeq I_0(a,A) =\int^\infty_{-\infty}  \dfrac{x^2 \exp(-x^2)}{1+Aa^{-1}\exp(-x^2)} dx = -\frac{\sqrt\pi a}{2A} \operatorname{Li}_{3/2}(-A/a)\,.$$
Here, Li$_s$ is the [polylogarithm function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).
In fact, $I_0$ is an excellent approximation to $I$ for $a\lesssim 0.1$.

The polylogarithm function has a known asymptotic expansions in terms of $\log x$. In particular, we have ($x\gg 1$)
$$ \operatorname{Li}_s(-x) \sim - \frac{\log^{s}(x)}{\Gamma(s)} \Bigl(1 + O(\log^{-2}(x))\Bigr)\,.$$

As a result, we obtain
$$ I(a,A) \simeq I_0(a,A) \sim \frac{2 a}{3A} \log^{3/2}(A/a)\,. $$

Note that this is not a rigorous mathematical answer. What remains is to show that $I- I_0$ is small for $a\to0$. Numerically, it seems to hold that $I- I_0 = o(a^2)$.

Comment: I am not sure if the rigorous proof of $I-I_0$ is not hard.

Comment: @mnmn1993: you have to subdivide the combined integral $I-I_0$ in different regimes. For the integral over $x\in[0,1]$, you can expand the integrand and easily obtain that it is $O(a^2)$ For $x\in[1,\infty]$, you can use $x\gg a$, to show that it is $o(a^2)$. A tighter bound might be indeed more difficult to obtain.